# Cannot Install Fixture: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: python, json, django, fixture, loaddata

I'm working on a website which allows users to nominate and vote for different positions. I use Python 2.7 and Django 1.10. The position objects were added through django's admin interface on the actual server. Therefore, my local server is empty of any positions. I wanted to add the positions to my local server for the sake of development. I ran the command `python manage.py dumpdata voting.Position --=2 > voting/fixtures/default_positions.json`.
The fixture has been made, and now I want to loaddata. When I run `python manage.py loaddata voting/fixtures/default_positions.json` (on my local dir. not the website's/server's one), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 64, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 104, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 167, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 201, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 889, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 939, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 652, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Problem installing fixture '/home/Saleha/trabd/voting/fixtures/default_positions.json': Could not load voting.Position(pk=1): file is encrypted or is not a database
```

The fixture file: https://pastebin.com/avRzHQyf  (too long for this place)

I need to say, as well, that `python manage.py runserver` doesn't work, nor does `python manage.py makemigrations`; and all that happens is that this same error pops up.
If no solution, could someone at least guide me to how to undo the loaddata command, so at least I can get my local server running I again?

I apologize for the long introduction, but I'm relatively new to programming and thought I should explain as much as I can. My error could be in the simplest and silliest of places.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For deleting the local database: I ran `rm db.sqlite3` , and now I can `runserver` and all. However, the original problem is still not resolved.